# How to make category wise product in JSON format

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have one array. In that array `categoryName` means we have to make multidimensional array, otherwise we have to make normal array. i tried but i am not able to make my expected JSON Format.

> print_r($search_result);

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [productId] => 1
            [categoryName] => Shoes
            [brandName] => Adidas
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [productId] => 2
            [categoryName] => Jeans
            [brandName] => LEVIS
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [productId] => 3
            [categoryName] => Jeans
            [brandName] => LEVIS
        )

)
```

using this array i want to make like this JSON Format

```
    {
  "status": "Success",
  "data": [
    {
      "categoryName": "Shoes",
      "products": [
        {
          "productId": "1",
          "brandName": "Adidas"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "categoryName": "Jeans",
      "products": [
        {
          "productId": "2",
          "brandName": "LEVIS"
        },
        {
          "productId": "2",
          "brandName": "LEVIS"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

for getting above my expected results i tried like this but is not happening. i am getting json format

```
protected function getCategorywiseProducts(){
        if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
            $this->response('',406);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT productId,categoryName,brandName FROM product";
        $mainArray = array();
        $search_result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
        $tasks = array();
        foreach ($search_result as $key => $value) {
            $tasks[$value['categoryName']][] = $value;
        }
        if(count($tasks)>0) {
            $response_array['status']='success';
            $response_array['categories'][]=$tasks;
            $this->response($this->json($response_array), 200);
        } else {
            $response_array['status']='fail';
            $response_array['message']='Record not found.';
            $response_array['data']='';
            $this->response($this->json($response_array), 204);
        }
    }
```

I am getting like this JSON format

```
    {
    "status": "success",
    "categories": [
        {
            "Shoes": [
                {
                    "productId": "1",
                    "categoryName": "Shoes",
                    "brandName": "Adidas"
                }
            ],
            "Jeans": [
                {
                    "productId": "2",
                    "categoryName": "Jeans",
                    "brandName": "LEVIS"
                },
                {
                    "productId": "3",
                    "categoryName": "Jeans",
                    "brandName": "LEVIS"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: _I am not able to make my expected JSON output_ Ask yourself: If I would scroll over StackOverflow questions and would read that title, is there a chance to imagine, what the questioneer's problem is? The next step would be to do the same with your question itself. If you have problems writing textes in english, please ask a friend to help you out. Take a look at [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my expected output using my array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645731/how-to-make-my-expected-output-using-my-array)

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the function like this:

```
protected function getCategorywiseProducts(){
    if($this->get_request_method() != "GET"){
        $this->response('',406);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT productId,categoryName,brandName FROM product";
    $mainArray = array();
    $search_result = $this->GetJoinRecord($sql);
    $tasks = array();
    foreach ($search_result as $key => $value) {
        $tasks['categoryName'][$key] = $value['categoryName'];
        $tasks['products']['productId'][$key] = $value['productId'];
        $tasks['products']['brandName'][$key] = $value['brandName'];
    }
    if(count($tasks)>0) {
        $response_array['status']='success';
        $response_array['categories'][]=$tasks;
        $this->response($this->json($response_array), 200);
    } else {
        $response_array['status']='fail';
        $response_array['message']='Record not found.';
        $response_array['data']='';
        $this->response($this->json($response_array), 204);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've only changed the `foreach` loop.

Comment: This is not my expected answer

Comment: {
    "status": "success",
    "categories": [
        {
            "categoryName": [
                "Shoes",
                "Jeans",
                "Jeans"
            ],
            "products": {
                "productId": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ],
                "brandName": [
                    "Adidas",
                    "LEVIS",
                    "LEVIS"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Mr@Amit Merchant,you checked above results,  this is not my expected results